# iPad reducing JPEG dimensions in mobile Safari/UIWebView

Tags: ios, image, ipad, mobile-safari, jpeg

When viewing images through an iPad (2 and 3) I find that jpeg images are having their dimensions halved in size.

For example an image with the dimesnions `1500 * 1000` will be rendered as `750 * 500`. If I copy the image from the iPad and email it to myself then I can see that the dimensions are still `1500 * 1000`.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to stop it from happening?

PNG images with the same dimensions are showing correctly without a problem and I do not think it is anything to do with file size as the some of the jpg images are smaller in size than the png images.

Comment: Where do you see the wrong dimensions? What app/code do you use to load/view the images.

Comment: How is this developer related?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe the images are viewed through Safari. We have an html5 app and an iOS app (the iOS makes use of Safari rendering) and it happens in both instances. I cannot reproduce the error in Safari desktop, even with an iPad user agent so I think it must be the iOS that is doing it.

Comment: And how is Mobile Safari reporting the wrong dimensions? Or is it just downscaling the images (as it always does when something does not fit on the screen)?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe if I view the images using a direct url then safari places the dimensions in the browser tab. It does look like it is downscaling the image - but it does not do this with png images or some other jpeg images. This is a problem as we are providing online books so a png next to a jpeg is not working as they are rendering at different sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop iOS from "downscaling" JPEG images then you need to use [progressive JPEG files](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-11.html).

To create these on the fly (along with optimizing the iamge) you can use [JpegTran](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_jpegtran.htm) using the following command:

```
jpegtran -copy none -progressive -optimize -outfile output.jpg input.jpg
```

I found an interesting article that discusses whether we should be using progressive JPEGs on the iPad and speculates why progressive Jpegs work where others fail:

http://duncandavidson.com/blog/2012/03/retina_web_thoughts

Please feel free to contribute or comment on this answer if you have any further information or recommendations on this topic.